# Rotating entities (orbiting)

Tags: c++, rotation, sfml

Using C++ and SFML. I have three entities. We will call them the Sun, the Earth, and the Moon.

First up, the sun, non-moving at all.
Second, the earth, rotating around the sun, this seems to work just fine.
Lastly, the moon, which does keep in rotation to a point but seems to be doing a large oval around the earth instead of doing a generic rotation around it. When I actually stop the earth from rotating, the moon rotates fine.

I am assuming that the earth position changing is effecting how the moon should rotate.

```
sf::Transform rotation;
rotation.rotate(mOrbitSpeed * dt.asSeconds(), mParent->getPosition());
sf::Vector2f positionAfterRotation = rotation.transformPoint(getPosition());
setPosition(positionAfterRotation);
```

The origin of the planets are set to the middle, I.E. so getPosition() gets the center of the planet as well. Get position returns the x and y coordinates. 
mParent would be the orbiting parent (I.E. Sun for Earth.)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You want a simple circular orbit in the Earth's reference frame, but you're doing the rotations in the Sun's reference frame. I'm surprised you get a result as well-behaved as an oval. Rotate the Moon about the Sun with the Earth's orbital motion, then about the Earth with the Moon's orbital motion, and you'll be all right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Beta said above, the coding above has been changed. Might as well share.

```
sf::Transform orbitalRotation;
orbitalRotation.rotate(mOrbitSpeed * dt.asSeconds(), mParent->getPosition());

if (mParent->mCanOrbit && mParent->mOrbitSpeed != 0.f)
    orbitalRotation.combine(mParent->getOrbitRotation());

sf::Vector2f positionAfterRotation = orbitalRotation.transformPoint(getPosition());
setPosition(positionAfterRotation);
mRotation = orbitalRotation;
```

Pretty much what is done here is that I store the rotation and combine it with the parents rotation speed if there is any. mRotation is a saved variable. You might want to initialize it with an initial rotation value but other then that it seem to rotate. Also tested with the moon having a 'mini-satellite' attached, and it also worked fine three deep.

Thanks!